# error TS2306: '...index.d.ts' is not a module

Tags: typescript, amd, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write a lib in Typescript that I want to use in various other typescript or JS projects. All of the those other projects run in browsers.

My Typescript lib project has multiple files, and each file is a React component with 1 class and 1-2 interfaces (Component + Props + State, for those that are familiar with React).

I want my component library to be importable as an AMD module by the other projects, and I want all of the compiled JS code to be bundled in a single file as part of the library's build process.

So far I've managed to set everything up so that my lib compiles. I've set up the compiler with the following options : `jsx: "react", declaration: true, module: "amd"`

The generated code for the lib looks like:

```
define("epb-widget/WidgetItemNav", ["require", "exports", "react"], function (require, exports, React) {
    "use strict";
    exports.WidgetItemNav = ...;
});
define("epb-widget/WidgetItemInfo", ["require", "exports", "react"], function (require, exports, React) {
    "use strict";
    exports.WidgetItemInfo = ...;
});
define("epb-widget/WidgetItem", ["require", "exports", "react", "epb-widget/WidgetItemNav", "epb-widget/WidgetItemInfo"], function (require, exports, React, WidgetItemNav_1, WidgetItemInfo_1) {
    "use strict";
    exports.WidgetItem = ...;
});
define("epb-widget/WidgetOptions", ["require", "exports", "react"], function (require, exports, React) {
    "use strict";
    exports.WidgetOptions = ...;
});
define("epb-widget/Widget", ["require", "exports", "react", "epb-widget/WidgetItem", "epb-widget/WidgetOptions"], function (require, exports, React, WidgetItem_1, WidgetOptions_1) {
    "use strict";
    exports.Widget = ...;
});
define("epb-widget", ["require", "exports", "epb-widget/Widget", "epb-widget/WidgetItem", "epb-widget/WidgetItemInfo", "epb-widget/WidgetItemNav", "epb-widget/WidgetOptions"], function (require, exports, Widget_1, WidgetItem_2, WidgetItemInfo_2, WidgetItemNav_2, WidgetOptions_2) {
    "use strict";
    exports.Widget = Widget_1.Widget;
    exports.WidgetItem = WidgetItem_2.WidgetItem;
    exports.WidgetItemInfo = WidgetItemInfo_2.WidgetItemInfo;
    exports.WidgetItemNav = WidgetItemNav_2.WidgetItemNav;
    exports.WidgetOptions = WidgetOptions_2.WidgetOptions;
});
```

That's a lot of AMD modules for my taste, but I can live with it. The generated code looks like it would work well.

The generated `.d.ts` file looks like that:

```
declare module "epb-widget/WidgetItemNav" {
    import * as React from "react";
    export interface WidgetItemNavProps {
        ...
    }
    export class WidgetItemNav extends React.Component<WidgetItemNavProps, void> {
        ...
    }
}
declare module "epb-widget/WidgetItemInfo" {
    export interface WidgetItemInfoProps {
        ...
    }
    export const WidgetItemInfo: (props: WidgetItemInfoProps) => JSX.Element;
}
declare module "epb-widget/WidgetItem" {
    export interface WidgetItemProps {
        ...
    }
    export const WidgetItem: (props: WidgetItemProps) => JSX.Element;
}
declare module "epb-widget/WidgetOptions" {
    import * as React from "react";
    export interface WidgetOptionsProps {
        ...
    }
    export interface WidgetOptionsState {
        ...
    }
    export class WidgetOptions extends React.Component<WidgetOptionsProps, WidgetOptionsState> {
        ...
    }
}
declare module "epb-widget/Widget" {
    import * as React from "react";
    import { WidgetItemProps } from "epb-widget/WidgetItem";
    export interface WidgetProps {
        ...
    }
    export interface WidgetState {
        ...
    }
    export class Widget extends React.Component<WidgetProps, WidgetState> {
        ...
    }
}
declare module "epb-widget" {
    export { Widget, WidgetProps } from "epb-widget/Widget";
    export { WidgetItem, WidgetItemProps } from "epb-widget/WidgetItem";
    export { WidgetItemInfo, WidgetItemInfoProps } from "epb-widget/WidgetItemInfo";
    export { WidgetItemNav, WidgetItemNavProps } from "epb-widget/WidgetItemNav";
    export { WidgetOptions, WidgetOptionsProps } from "epb-widget/WidgetOptions";
}
```

Again, that looks quite reasonable. And that was all output directly by the Typescript compiler.

Finally, this library is an npm module, and its `package.json` looks like this

```
{
  "name": "epb-widget",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "typings": "./dist/index",
  "globalDependencies": {...},
  "devDependencies": {...}
}
```

**But here's the problem**

When I try to use the library in one of my projects, it doesn't actually work.

I simply try import the classes like this:

```
import {Widget, WidgetProps, WidgetItem} from "epb-widget";
```

but the typescript compiler throws the following error

```
 error TS2656: Exported external package typings file '.../node_modules/epb-widget/dist/index.d.ts' is not a module. Please contact the package author to update the package definition.
```

I honestly can't figure out what I should do here. `index.d.ts` was generated by `tsc`, and I'm not sure why that very same `tsc` isn't able to consume it in another project.

Comment: The generated .d.ts looks like external module definitions, which is not what is expected for definitions files pointed to by the 'typings' parameter. I do this successfully with 'commonjs'; Is it an 'amd' issue ? What does you generated .d.ts look like if you choose 'commonjs' ?

Comment: Hmm, I shouldn't use the "typings" parameter in the `package.json` of the library then?

Comment: Yes. I would think so. In the dependent projects, try using the generated .d.ts as an external typings files as you would do with a "pure" js library

Comment: Yup, it works. If you want to turn your comment into an actual answer, I'll upvote it and accept it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For reference, do you mind pointing out where in the docs it mentions that there is a difference between the type definitions loaded via the `typings` folder in project vs the ones loaded via the `typings` property of  `package.json`. I really didn't see it anywhere.

Comment: Cannot find it.. but if you loot at [this project](https://github.com/jvitor83/typings-packagejson) which is the result of an SO discussion on this subject, the generated typings in `dist` look the same as the one I generate using commonjs i.e. one per file, non external and an `index.ts` that re-exports it al

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is too long to go into our discussion above but here is my TL;DR to create a library:

- create an `index.ts` that re-exports the definitions exposed in the library e.g.

  ```
  export * from './API'
  export * from './Decorators'
  ...
  ```
- compile the library files with the `--declaration` flag to automatically generate the typings
- add a `typings` entry to `package.json` pointing to the generated `index.d.ts` file

To use the library:

- drop it in the `node_modules` folder like any other library
- simply `import * as mylib from 'mylib'`: it will automatically import all the exported definitions *and* the typings

This process works perfectly fine with `commonjs` and from what I understand, with `systemjs` too. I do not know about `amd`, and your generated typings look quite different from mine:

The generated `index.d.ts` typically looks like

```
export * from './API';
export * from './Decorators';
...
```

and the `API.d.ts` file will typically look like

```
import * as stream from 'stream';
import * as net from 'net';
import * as url from 'url';
export interface Factory {
    end(): Promise<void>;
}
export interface ChannelFactory extends Factory {
    getChannel(name: string, closeListener?: () => void): Promise<Channel>;
    existsChannel(name: string): Promise<boolean>;
}
....
```

Comment: Apparently, the issue is that it works fine as longs as you DON'T combine the type declarations into a single file (ie: if you use `--outDir` it works, if you use `--out` it doesn't). From a few more tests I did today and from the links you provided, it seems that the best way to properly package everything is to do 2 passes on the TS code. 1st pass generates the JS code packed into one file. Second pass generates the type definitions as separate files. Then everybody is happy.

Comment: Good to know!  ... and glad you have a solution.

Comment: @LordOfThePigs thanks, 4 years later it's still relevant...

Comment: 5 years later and still relevant. I have generated `lib/index.js` with webpack and type definitions with TS. TS spits out separate .d.ts files, e.g. `lib/src/Text.d.ts` and `lib/src/Title.d.ts`. However, type definitions cannot be recognised if I use `--outFile` to produce single `lib/index.d.ts` combining both Text.d.ts and Title.d.ts. Have anyone managed to solve this?

Comment: Hey @igor, same here. And I need to use --outFile since it's a Bazel target and it needs to be a single file. Could you solve it yet?

Answer (score 0):

you can use
ctr + shift + P  and reload the windows
its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

add "moduleResolution": "node" in the option at the tsconfig.json